# Documentation in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, documentation, apex

I have a very general question and actually not quite sure if it belongs here.
But I am asking myself how do developers in practice document pages in oracle apex with all their processes,dynamic actions, computations etc. document since it definitely differs from a traditional development process.
So that another developer knows exactly what has been done.

Is there a standard for how an application should be documented in Oracle APEX or does anyone know how it is done in practice?

If this topic does not belong here I will close the question:)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what I do; I understand that other people might be doing it differently, or not at all. I'd like to hear their opinion as well, I might learn something.

I write a lot of comments, everywhere. Most of my "logic" is in packages within the database. All procedures and functions are well documented. All my tables have comments as well (on a table and most of their columns).

Apex just calls procedures/functions, I don't write a lot of code there. Certainly, you can't avoid writing `select` statements for e.g. interactive reports etc. If necessary, I write **comments** (it is the last property, in the bottom-right corner of Apex screen).

If someone knows how Apex works, it is fairly simple - on fairly simple pages - to follow its execution. Running the page in debug mode also helps, as it leads you through the process.

After application enters production, I also have a MS Word document which contains information about what's being changed on a certain page, when and why.

We've been discussing recently that it would be nice if someone investigates possibility of using [Git](https://git-scm.com/). We haven't done it yet (too few people, too much daily jobs to do. Classic).

Answer (score 0):

There is a section for writing the Comments for every element (Region,item etc..) in an APEX page. Please use this section to write the comments.
Where will the comments be available:
Click an element, you will find the comments in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

since APEX works with so many different technologies we end up doing multiple things

**HTML**

Hardly ever comment it because we try to keep it to a minimum. But if it ever got to that point it would be by commenting outer blocks

**CSS**

Similar to HTMl, we try not to use it, but in this case it is a bit harder so we create a comment at the header an index of things and explain some of the more complex queries

**JavaScript**

We use the [JSDOC](https://jsdoc.app/) style which works perfectly with VS Code.

**PL/SQL**

This one is probably the hardest one, but we try to standardize comments in all function and procedures. When a packacge is created both specification and body should have comments.